# Analyse clips in Adobe Premiere with warp stabilizer applied (jsx, ExtendScript)

Tags: javascript, adobe, extendscript

When exporting a Premiere sequence with warp stabilizer applied, which is not analysed, Premiere will show a big banner across the video.

Therefore I'm trying to write a script, what tells Premiere to analyse a clip, that has warp stabilizer applied.

So far I can get Premiere to give me information about the effects of a clip, but I can't find a way to trigger the "Analyse" button inside the warp stabilizer. Also ExtendedScript Toolkit documentation isn't very helpful at this.

How can I tell Premiere to analyse the clip?

Thats my script so far:

```
// get active sequence
var seq = app.project.activeSequence;
if (seq) {
  // get first video layer
  var firstVideoTrack = seq.videoTracks[0];
  if (firstVideoTrack) {
    // get first video clip
    var firstClip = firstVideoTrack.clips[0];
    if (firstClip) {
      // get effects applied to clip
      var clipComponents = firstClip.components;
      if (clipComponents) {
        // loop through effects to find match
        for (var i = 0; i < clipComponents.numItems; ++i) {
          if (clipComponents[i].matchName == "AE.ADBE SubspaceStabilizer") {
            var stabProps = clipComponents[i].properties;

            ?????????

            break;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```